# Using String and Pointer with malloc

Tags: c++, string, pointers, malloc

I cannot figure out why this program is not working. I got `Access Violation` message when trying to push a variabel with the type of data is string to another variable that had allocated at memory with malloc.

For example, first I declare the variable..

```
string pName;
address temp;
```

After that, I call the `Allocate` module..

```
temp = Allocate(pName, 1, 1, 200);
```

And here's the module..

```
#include <...>
#include<string>
#define Info(T) (T)->info
#define FirstSon(T) (T)->ps_fs
#define NextBro(T) (T)->ps_nb
#define Parent(T) (T)->ps_pr

using namespace std;
typedef struct infoElmt{
    string pName;
    float number;
    int type;       
    float price;
}compInfo;
typedef compInfo infotype;

typedef struct tElmtTree *address;
typedef struct tElmtTree {
    infotype info;
    address ps_fs, ps_nb, ps_pr;
} node;

typedef address DynTree;

address Allocate (string pName, float number, int type, float price)     //(string pName, float number, int unit, int type, float price
    {

        address P;

        P = (address) malloc (sizeof(node));

        if (P != NULL)
        {
            Info(P).type = type;
            Info(P).number = number;
            Info(P).price = price;

            FirstSon(P)  = NULL;
            NextBro(P) = NULL;
            Parent(P) = NULL;

            printf("OK");
            Info(P).pName = pName;
        }

        return (P);
    }
```

The error is came when the program run the `Info(P).pName = pName;` , I know it because if the `printf("OK");` moved to below `Info(P).pName = pName;` , the "OK" doesn't showed in the console.

Is it problem with malloc and string?

*Edit*

- The `#include<..>` is another *Include* like conio.h, etc.
- I'm forget to put the `using namespace std;` in the code..

Comment: `#include <...>` ??? And the presence of `string` makes this C++, a _different_ language to C.

Comment: Those macros are extremely pointless when you could just use the data members themselves. Even if not doing that, a normal function is still much better. And this is really C inside a C++ shell. Using `std::string` is the only C++ I can find. `malloc` is pretty much deprecated, `typedef`ing structs is no longer useful, objects shouldn't be passed by value when only reading them, and we have `nullptr`.

Comment: If you're writing C++, you should forget about using `malloc()` and use `new` instead.  If you're using `malloc()`, you should be writing C code.

Comment: @paxdiablo The '#include<..>' is another Include like conio.h, etc. About the 'string' I didn't know if it is C++ or C language.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Actually, now I'm learning the C language, but for input/output-in in the console I'm really like to use the C++ syntax, and from now, I know that is really bad idea to use C++ in C.
So, the string data type is C++ language?

Comment: `#include <string>` is not used in C; it is used in C++.  Therefore, your code is C++ and not C (unless you're doing something very eccentric and are providing the header file `string` and arranging to compile it instead of headers provided by the system).

Comment: @chris Actually, now I'm learning the C language, but for input/output-in in the console I'm really like to use the C++ syntax, and from now, I know that is really bad idea to use C++ in C.
So, the string data type is C++ language?

Comment: There is no `string` type in standard C — that is correct.  If you're learning C, use C and do not use C++; you will confuse yourself.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, Technically, smart pointers and vectors and all else in the RAII world (the string is a good start), but `new` is definitely better than `malloc`.

Comment: @AhmadNabili, You'd be better off compiling your source file as a C program instead of compiling as C++ and guessing what is and isn't C.

Comment: And, if you're using conio, get rid of it. The Borland compiler is seriously old tech and hasn't kept up to date with standards.

Comment: @chris: 'use `new` instead' was really a shorthand for 'do not use `malloc()` in C++; use the native C++ allocators'.  But you're right; it is best to avoid the raw use of `new` as much as possible.

Comment: @all Okay, thank you all. I will use the C language instead C++ because I still need the malloc and I didn't know to use`     new    ` but next I'll try it, and will use     `    char a[];    `    instead using the string data type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `new` and not `malloc`. Your structure seems to include a `std::string` and it cannot be initialized correctly when you allocate the structure using a `malloc`.

In C++ just don't use `malloc` at all unless you have some rare scenarios where you need just a block of uninitialized memory. Just use get yourself used to `new`.

On a different note do avoid dynamic allocations as much as possible. Perhaps you may want to use:

```
std::vector<std::string> obj;
```

Comment: Commenting here to avoid the mess under the questions...The reason the `OK` doesn't appear is because you didn't output a newline after it.  If you want a line of output to appear, output the newline: `printf("OK\n");` as otherwise the C standard I/O library buffers the output until a newline is printed, or the buffer overfills (which is probably over 500 characters on the one line of output).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `typedef` to define your struct, you need to use a pointer

```
address *p //you should always use lowercase to declare variables.
```

to have access to struct fields, since you're using a pointer you need to use `->` instead of `.`

```
Info(p)->type=type;
```

Comment: I'd define in the top of the code 
    #define Info(P) (P)->Info
So if I write Info(P) it means P->info. And about the dot(.)
    Info(P).pName
Because I'd declare that the "info" is another typedef data type
:D

Answer (score 0):

1. Use C++ `new` operator - not `malloc`
2. Why use these

   ```
   #define Info(T) (T)->info
   #define FirstSon(T) (T)->ps_fs
   #define NextBro(T) (T)->ps_nb
   #define Parent(T) (T)->ps_pr
   ```

   when you could use the member variables directly (or better still define getters and setters).
3. This line is pointless

   ```
   typedef compInfo infotype;
   ```
4. Look up `cout` - C++ way of printing to the console. `printf` is C.

When you fix these issues then the bug will be more evident.

i.e. Either program in C or C++.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Thanks - Was in the process of doing that edit myself.

Comment: [1] Ok, thank you for that suggestion.
 [2] Because it will make simple instead if I must write P-->Parent
 [3&4] Thanks, I forget about it

Comment: @AhmadNabili - For point 2 - How does it make it simpler? Certainly makes debugging a bit harder with the `#define` all over the shop.